# Getting directions using Google Maps My Location

Tags: google-maps

I would like to integrate a simple 'route to my store' using Google Maps MyLocation, for distribution through a mobile browser.

The perfect solution (from the end users viewpoint) would be - A plotted route from the Users GEO-Location, to a pre-configured POI (my store). That's it. I would like to avoid having the 'get directions' dialogue (it'll look squashy on a mobile device). Just a map with a start point, an end point and the route in between.

Comment: Your excuses for posting the question are longer than the question itself. I understand your frustration but please don't write so much irrelevant text. It costs others their time to read it all and it's more likely to be perceived as information noise than a relevant reason to view the question in a better light.

Comment: Maybe provide some more context? Platform or framework perhaps? Tags?

Comment: Tom, stop being a Nazi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain that this satisfies your goal of avoiding a "Get Directions" dialog, as it will certain involve an intermediate step by the user. But the dialog won't "look squashy" on a mobile device; indeed, it will be optimized for mobile viewing.

If you only plug in the daddr (destination address) coordinates to a map call, using the latitude and longitude of your store (or whatever location), Google Maps will try to set the start location to default to the user's "My Location" position if the device supports it, and otherwise will prompt the user to enter the start location. It will also allow the user to select which of the supported modes of transportation is desired (walk, bike, transit, or car).

This example plots the route from your location to the Martin Luther King, Jr. birth home in Atlanta:
https://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=33.755418,-84.371100

I tested this successfully on the following devices:

- Windows 7 desktop using Chrome;
- Windows 7 desktop using Firefox;
- Windows 7 desktop using Internet Explorer;
- Android phone with Jelly Bean OS using installed Google Maps app;
- Android phone with Jelly Bean OS using the default browser;
- Android phone with Jelly Bean OS using Chrome;
- iPhone with iOS6 using the default browser.

Based on the consistency of the responses I got in those tests, I feel confident it would work in most, if not all, scenarios.